# UserControl binding inside popup control using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am trying to load a UserControl inside a wpf popup control, From the code below i can see the Popup opening with yellow background but the **ContentControl** with **View is not getting loaded**. I am using Caliburn Micro to resolve View and ViewModel.
Below is my xaml, The contentcontrol outside the pop works fine, But the same content control inside Popup displays only the yellow background.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="SearchListViewModel" />
                <ToggleButton Name="button1">
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <TextBlock Text="Select" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                </ToggleButton>
                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button1}" StaysOpen="False">
                    <Border>
                        <StackPanel
                            Width="500"
                            Height="500"
                            Background="Yellow"
                            Orientation="Vertical">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="SearchListViewModel" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
```

Comment: Assuming you are using the default view/view model resolution mechanism, then you should rename the content control to `SearchList` instead of `SearchListViewModel`. Your view should be called `SearchListView`. Caliburn assumes that the view model is called the name + ViewModel on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is somewhat late, but Caliburn Micro won't/can't discover `ContentControl` inside a `Popup` control. Thus the content control won't bind to the `SearchListViewModel` property.

You can, however, specify the correct bind path:

```xml
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=SearchListViewModel,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

*note:*
you also need to reference the `cal` namespace:

```xml
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
```